# Foreach multiplicando resultados vindo do banco de dados (PHP/Wordpress)

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, wordpress

Como fazer para o foreach não multiplique os resultados vindo do banco de dados?

Eu tenho a seguinte função:

```
$categoriess = (array) get_terms( 'job_category', array('hide_empty'=>false) );

echo '<pre>'; print_r($categoriess); echo '</pre>';

Array
(
    [0] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 53
            [name] => Administrador Banco de Dados - DBA
            [slug] => administrador-banco-de-dados-dba
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 53
            [taxonomy] => job_category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
        )

    [1] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 54
            [name] => Administrador de Dados - AD
            [slug] => administrador-de-dados-ad
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 54
            [taxonomy] => job_category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
        )

    [2] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 55
            [name] => Administrador de Redes
            [slug] => administrador-de-redes
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 55
            [taxonomy] => job_category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
        )

    [3] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 56
            [name] => Administrador de Sistemas
            [slug] => administrador-de-sistemas
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 56
            [taxonomy] => job_category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
        )

    [4] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 58
            [name] => Analista DBM
            [slug] => analista-dbm
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 58
            [taxonomy] => job_category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
        )

    [5] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 59
            [name] => Analista de Aplicações
            [slug] => analista-de-aplicacoes
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 59
            [taxonomy] => job_category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 1
            [filter] => raw
        )

    [6] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 60
            [name] => Analista de BI
            [slug] => analista-de-bi
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 60
            [taxonomy] => job_category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
        )
      ... e assim por diante trazendo todas as categorias cadastradas no banco de dados
)
```

E tenho esse SELECT que realiza uma consulta no banco de dados trazendo os valores que eu quero.

```
foreach ($categoriess as $key) {
        $query10 = $wpdb->get_results("
            SELECT * FROM $wpdb->usermeta LEFT JOIN $wpdb->users ON($wpdb->users.ID = $wpdb->usermeta.user_id) LEFT JOIN $wpdb->posts ON($wpdb->posts.post_author = $wpdb->users.ID)
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id)
            WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'noo_resume'
            AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
            AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_job_category'
            AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%{$key->term_id}%'
            AND $wpdb->usermeta.meta_key = '_jm_candidate_field_clocknow_user_btn'
            AND $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value = 'value_1'
        ");

        foreach ($query10 as $vaga) {
                echo 'Nome: ' .$vaga->display_name. '<br>';
                echo 'Currículo: ' .$vaga->post_title. '<br>';
                echo 'Term ID: ' .$vaga->meta_value. '<br>';
                echo 'Cargo: ' .$key->name. '<br>';
                echo '<hr>';
        }
    }
```

O resultado da consulta é o seguinte:

Nome: Rodrigo Fontes Santos

Currículo: Teste

Term ID: ["55","56","60"]

Cargo: Administrador de Redes

---

Nome: Rodrigo Fontes Santos

Currículo: Teste

Term ID: ["55","56","60"]

Cargo: Administrador de Sistemas

---

Nome: Rodrigo Fontes Santos

Currículo: Teste

Term ID: ["55","56","60"]

Cargo: Analista de BI

---

O problema é que o `foreach` está multiplicando os resultados pelo número das categorias do currículo, o certo seria:

Nome: Rodrigo Fontes Santos

Currículo: Teste

Term ID: ["55","56","60"]

Cargo: Administrador de Redes, Administrador de Sistemas, Analista de BI.

Como fazer para que o foreach não multiplique os resultados?

Comment: Mesmo não sendo o foco da pergunta, mas o seu algoritmo está muito ruim. Amigo, nunca faça select ou qualquer outra interação com a base de dados dentro de um loop.

Comment: @Cesar, obrigado pelo Feedback, sou novato no back end.

Answer (score 2):

Alguma dessas tabelas que você deu join está causando esta duplicidade, precisa descobrir qual é e utilizar `group by` de maneira correta.

Para descobrir, é interessante você adicionar no SELECT a chave primária de 
cada tabela do LEFT JOIN e ver qual coluna que é diferente para cada linha, esta coluna será a responsável pela duplicidade, então você terá de remove-la do SELECT e *talvez* adicionar as demais colunas em `group by`.